# Adding image on THREE.js plane

Tags: vue.js, three.js, 3d

I am trying to put an .png img on my plane, but when I try to load it, it disappears.

It may be that THREE.js is not made for Vue.js, is there any other 3D-Library that supports Vue.js?

I also want to add an SVG, THREE has an SVGLoader which I have not figured out how it works yet.

```
<template>
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as THREE from 'three'
//import { SVGLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js';
export default {
  name: 'Three',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null,
      shape: null,
      geomarty: null,
      stats: null,
      gui: null,
      guiData: null,
      texture: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init(){
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
        this.texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../img/shark.png')
        this.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: this.texture})
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
        this.scene.add( this.mesh );
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
    },
    animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );
    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      this.animate();
      //this.svgLoad();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please limit questions to one per ...question. Stack Overflow only allows you to accept one answer per question. Your SVG question should be presented as a new question. If it is dependent on this question, just wait until this question is resolved before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Your animation function might be losing context. When you call it via `requestAnimationFrame`, the `this` turns into `window`. When I want to avoid this, I usually [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the animation function to the desired context.

I'm not super-familiar with Vue, but try this...

```
<script>
import * as THREE from 'three'
let boundAnimation = null
export default {
  //...
  methods:
    // ...
    animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame( boundAnimation );
      this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      boundAnimation = this.animate.bind(this);
      boundAnimation();
  }
}
</script>
```

Inside `mounted`, the `this` should represent the current implementation of the exported object. By assigning `boundAnimation` in this manner, all calls to `boundAnmation` will use for context the same `this` as when the function was bound. Using the bound function in `requestAnimationFrame` ensures that when that function fires, it will still be using the desired `this` context.